# Is the OAuth Flow necessary to Register a User and Add a funding Source

Tags: dwolla

What is the flow currently enabled by the API to register a user and add a funding source?
As far as I can tell, it seems I would need to:

1. Call "Register User" to create the account
2. Follow the OAuth flow in order to get the new user's auth tokens
3. Make an authenticated call to "Funding Sources - Add"

Is the OAuth Flow necessary to Register a User and Add a funding Source?

My question is very similar to the one Clay Gulick posed a couple months ago on the following GetSatisfaction thread, which hasn't been answered.
https://getsatisfaction.com/dwolla/topics/does_api_facilitate_to_add_bank_account_to_my_endusers_dwolla_account

Thanks for your help.

Comment: did I answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

oAuth of the user is not required to [`registerUser() (Requires Authentication: NO)`](https://developers.dwolla.com/dev/docs/register/register)  but is required to [`addFundingSource() (Requires Authentication: YES)`](https://developers.dwolla.com/dev/docs/funding/add). Depending on your language, the user's oAuth token is added like this (PHP):

```
$token='xxxxxxx'; //user's oAuth token
$Dwolla->setToken($token);
```

Note that you will need your Application keys, which are different from your oAuth token, for both API calls.